# Differential equations modeling: A tank of salt

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A tank contains 80 kg of salt and 1000 L of water. Pure water enters a tank at the rate 6 L/min. The solution is mixed and drains from the tank at the rate 7 L/min.

Let y be the number of kg of salt in the tank after t minutes.

The differential equation for this situation would be ??

I don't see how this question is even possible to answer. How does one know the change in salt when I don't know anything about what happening to salt? The question doesn't specify. For all I know the salt never leaves the tank right?

The answer given is

(-7*y)/(1000-1*t)

But this answer doesn't make any sense. It doesn't take into consideration the salt or the 6 liters entering the tank?
Is this the correct answer?

Can someone explain this to me ? Thank you!

Comment: Salt does leave the tank when solution is drained from the tank

Comment: But how can I possibly know the rate based on the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be the amount of salt left in the tank after $t$ minutes.

Each minute $6L$ of water is pumped into the tank, and $7L$ leaves the tank, so overall $1L$ of water is drained from the tank. Then after $t$ minutes water left in the tank would be $(1000-t)L$.

Now at $t$ minutes, new $6L$ of water is pumped into the tank, so there are $1000-t+6$ water in the tank. The solution is mixed up, so that the concentration of salt is uniform throughout the solution. Concentration is now

$$
\frac{x}{1006-t}
$$

(unit is kg/L, but doesn't really matter).

Now exactly $7L$ of this solution is drained, meaning the salt drained out is exactly

$$
\frac{x}{1006-t}*7 (\text{kg})
$$

---

edit: above is slightly wrong because I didn't consider the fact that amount of pure water is decreased a bit more each time solution is drained from the tank. But now you have the idea, so you might prove that amount of pure water in the tank is constantly $1000L$ which proves the answer given is correct